# Could not load dynamic library "libjack.dylib"

Tags: macos, jack, bitwig

I'm trying to install JACK on MacOs for use in Bitwig.  I appear to have JACK installed correctly, but am getting the error:

> could not load dynamic library "libjack.dylib"
> [image]

This is all the error information I have.  Any idea what's going on?

---

UPDATE 1: Found a trail https://github.com/jackaudio/jack2/issues/640

There may be some issues between using Jack2 and the original Jack for OSX... though my version appears to be 1.9.20.

UPDATE 2: Tried installing both the intel and universal versions of 1.9.20, same issue for both

UPDATE 3: `/urs/local/lib/libjack.dylib` exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this email in response from support:

> Hello,
>
> we're sorry, but since the security changes for macOS Catalina Bitwig Studio does not work with JACK audio on macos.
> What exactly are you trying to do that can't be achieved with Coreaudio?
>
> Best regards,
>
> Bitwig Technical Support Team

But, as it turns out, CoreAudio on MacOS has the features I needed from JACK already.  Try searching applications for "Audio MIDI Setup" to see if it works for you.